# simperium: sqlite database restored to Xcode Simulator (Xcode 7.1.1). new records sync. old records don't

Tags: simperium

Question for Simperium:

A badly-written XC unit test wiped most data from a simperium user account (mine.) No problem. I moved a day-old back-up of the sqlite file into an iPhone 5 (iOS 9.1) simulator, and deleted the now-useless sqlite file from the same Documents directory.

I performed a clean (SHIFT-COMMAND-K), and started the simulator. All my missing data now appeared in the app simulator. Great.

BUT restored Core Data records did not then get synced to corresponding Simperium buckets. Puzzling as Simperium DID respond successfully to syncing new records on create, update, and delete actions.

I then deleted the entire data set on Simperium.com. Same result. New records syncing no problem, old records no.

Is there important meta-data that I deleted when deleting the old sqlite file. If so, (how) can I get old records to re-sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is: the method that should pick up those 'new old entities' is getting bypassed, because all of them already have both, a [Key + GhostData](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/blob/develop/Simperium/SPCoreDataStorage.m#L332).

This scenario should normally recover automatically, granted that those entities get updated somehow (that way the lib would pick them up and sync them with the backend).

The easiest way to force a re-upload would be:

- In your app, add a (temporary + helper method) that gets executed *right* after Simperium is initialized (and thus, the Core Data stack is wired), but before the `authenticate` method is called.
- Loop through all of the entities in that bucket and set to nil both, the *simperiumKey* and *ghostData* value.
- Run your app just once
- Kill this helper method (otherwise it'd probably cause duplicate entries!).

(Untested), but that should do the trick!

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks. It may take a while to verify, as I have not yet gotten deep into the simperium-ios codebase.

Comment: No problem!. If anything, please, feel free to open an issue on the official github repository.

Comment: I ended up running bare-metal sqlite commands on the backed-up db to set ZSIMPERIUMKEY and ZGHOSTDATA to null .  Example:  "UPDATE [mydb] SET ZSIMPERIUMKEY = NULL". I repeated this for each entity / table. I then moved the cleaned-up  back-up db into the Simulator Documents folder and deleted the old Model.sqlite file. Then ran the app. Everything synced up nicely. Thanks for that! I was surprised when I manually deleted all user data from the Simperium dashboard that sync did not then work for the previously sync'd records. But maybe something about online / offline sync makes this hard.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's sorted out! happy holidays sir!